# Drupal upgrade from 5.3 to 7 version (required upgrade to PHP 5.3 throws deprecated warnings)

Tags: php, drupal, upgrade

It is feasible to relatively easily upgrade drupal installation
from current 5.3 version (rather old) to newer like 6 or 7.
Such that supports newer version of PHP.
Old versions of PHP are disabled in my hosting company
and newer PHP version causes many deprecation warnings error on drupal-based website.

It seems rather tedious process to make such upgrades anyone go through it and have any clues
tutorials, or know whether it is worth doing. This website gives a little profits from adsense. I would do this myself in weekends as this is to little to pay for some support or developer.

Maybe better idea is to manually replaces just does lines that are causing erros

like:

```
: Function ereg() is deprecated in /home2/domain/public_html/includes/file.inc on line 647.
```

But when i do this changes I understood that this does not rule out further possibilities of upgrades to newer drupal versions

Comment: You wont be able to automatically "upgrade" like you can from D7 to D8. You would be able to migrate though. If doing so, you might as well migrate to D9. You could make use of the migrate module and write your own migrate classes, or maybe make use of the feeds module.

Comment: What version is you drupal instance?